# Primeiro decremento em JavaScript com operador de pós-decremento ("numero--") difere de "numero - 1"

Tags: javascript, operadores

Sabe-se que em javascript `numero--` subtrai 1 do valor de `numero` e equivale a: `numero = numero-1`;

Então por que há diferença no resultado na execução das duas formas?

**Forma 1:**

```
var numero = 10;
console.log (numero);
var diminuirNumero = numero--;
console.log(diminuirNumero);
```

**Forma 2:**

```
var outroNumero = 10;
console.log (outroNumero);
var diminuirOutroNumero = outroNumero-1;
console.log(diminuirOutroNumero);
```

**Executando**

```js
var numero = 10;
console.log (numero);
var diminuirNumero = numero--;
console.log(diminuirNumero);

var outroNumero = 10;
console.log (outroNumero);
var diminuirOutroNumero = outroNumero-1;
console.log(diminuirOutroNumero);
```

Comment: As 3 respostas são idênticas, vou marcar como aceita a resposta mais antiga ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso acontece porque `numero--` retorna o valor de `numero` **antes** de decrementá-lo:

```js
var numero = 10;
console.log(numero); // 10

// primeiro retorna o valor atual (10) e depois decrementa
console.log(numero--); // 10

// depois de decrementado
console.log(numero); // 9
```

---

Se quer retornar o valor depois do decremento, basta usar `--numero`:

```js
var numero = 10;
console.log(numero); // 10
var diminuirNumero = --numero;
console.log(diminuirNumero); // 9
```

Pois assim o número é primeiro decrementado, e depois o resultado é retornado:

```js
var numero = 10;
console.log(numero); // 10

// primeiro decrementa e depois retorna o valor (9)
console.log(--numero); // 9

// depois de decrementado
console.log(numero); // 9
```

Mais detalhes na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement) e na [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-postfix-decrement-operator) <- aliás, neste link tem uma descrição detalhada deste comportamento:

#### *Postfix Decrement Operator*

- `UpdateExpression:LeftHandSideExpression--`

  - Let `lhs` be the result of evaluating `LeftHandSideExpression`.
  - Let `oldValue` be `ToNumeric(GetValue(lhs))`.
  - Let `newValue` be `Type(oldValue)::subtract(oldValue, Type(oldValue)::unit)`.
  - Perform `PutValue(lhs, newValue)`.
  - Return `oldValue`.

#### *Prefix Decrement Operator*

- `UpdateExpression:--UnaryExpression`

  - Let `expr` be the result of evaluating `UnaryExpression`.
  - Let `oldValue` be `ToNumeric(GetValue(expr))`.
  - Let `newValue` be `Type(oldValue)::subtract(oldValue, Type(oldValue)::unit)`.
  - Perform `PutValue(expr, newValue)`.
  - Return `newValue`.

Ou seja, o *postfix operator* (`numero--`) retorna o valor que o número tinha antes do decremento, já o *prefix operator* (`--numero`) retorna o valor que o número tem depois que o decremento é feito. Mas ambos atualizam o valor de `numero`.

---

Por fim, se não quer alterar o valor de `numero`, aí você faz `numero - 1`. E nesse caso funciona porque primeiro é feita a conta `numero - 1`, e depois o resultado é atribuído para `diminuirNumero`.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação, quando usado como sufixo, o operador de decremento retorna o valor **antes** da operação e, quando usado como prefixo, retorna o valor **depois** de decrementar.

> [**Decrement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement)
>
> ```js
> let x = 3;
> const y = x--;
>
> console.log(`x:${x}, y:${y}`);
> // expected output: "x:2, y:3"
>
> let a = 3;
> const b = --a;
>
> console.log(`a:${a}, b:${b}`);
> // expected output: "a:2, b:2"
> ```
>
> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, `x--`), the decrement operator decrements and returns the value before decrementing.
>
> If used prefix, with operator before operand (for example, `--x`), the decrement operator decrements and returns the value after decrementing.

Em tradução livre:

> [**Decremento**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement)
>
> ```js
> let x = 3;
> const y = x--;
>
> console.log(`x:${x}, y:${y}`);
> // saída esperada: "x:2, y:3"
>
> let a = 3;
> const b = --a;
>
> console.log(`a:${a}, b:${b}`);
> // saída esperada: "a:2, b:2"
> ```
>
> Se usado como sufixo, com operador após o operando (por exemplo, `x--`), o operador de decremento diminui e retorna o valor **antes** de decrementar.
>
> Se for usado como prefixo, com operador antes do operando (por exemplo, `--x`), o operador de decremento diminui e retorna o valor depois de decrementar.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece, pois existe uma diferença em utilizar o operador `--` (ou `++`) e a outra forma (`x + 1` ou `x - 1`).

A diferença é a seguinte: quanto você faz usa o `++` (ou `--`), a ordem em que ele aparece faz diferença: quanto ele aparece antes da variável, o cálculo é executado e o resultado é retornado.

Quando o operador é colocado após a variável, o resultado é retornado antes.

Quando você utiliza: `valor + 1` (ou `valor - 1`) , o cálculo é feito antes da atribuição.